# Yii2: can't upload file through FileUploadUI

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, multifile-uploader

I'm trying to upload a file through `FileUploadUI::widget` in yii2 advanced. But I can't achieve my goal. I don't know what the problem is, but the file doesn't appear in the folder I wish to upload to.

this is my view

```
<?= FileUploadUI::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'attribute' => 'img',
        'url' => ['image-upload', 'id' => $model],
        'gallery' => false,
        'fieldOptions' => [
            'accept' => 'image/*'
        ],
        'clientOptions' => [
            'maxFileSize' => 2000000
        ],
        // ...
        'clientEvents' => [
            'fileuploaddone' => 'function(e, data) {
                                console.log(e);
                                console.log(data);
                            }',
            'fileuploadfail' => 'function(e, data) {
                                console.log(e);
                                console.log(data);
                            }',
        ],
    ]); ?>
```

this is controller my controller is into backend but I want to upload the file to **`frontend/web/img/temp`** action

```
public function actionImageUpload()
{
    $model = new MyNews();

    $imageFile = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'img');
    $directory = Yii::getAlias('/../frontend/web/img/temp/');

    if ($imageFile != null) { //can't saveAs() file into my ../img/temp/ folder
        $uid = 'qqqq';
        $fileName = $uid . '.' . $imageFile->extension;
        $filePath = $directory . $fileName;
        if ($imageFile->saveAs($filePath)) {
            $path = '/../frontend/web/img/temp/' . $fileName;
             //.....
        }
    }
        return '';
    }
```

Comment: I can suggest my extension: https://github.com/FabrizioCaldarelli/yii2-file-uploader

Comment: whats with  the long `Namespaces` dude @FabrizioCaldarelli

Comment: what are you doing here `$directory = Yii::getAlias('/../frontend/web/img/temp/');` if you need to upload it to frontend use `@frontend` with your path to web rather than like given above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `aliases` defined by Yii like `@frontend` `@backend` rather than providing the path inside the `Yii::getAlias()`, few common like i stated are defined in **`common/config/bootstrap.php`** like

```
Yii::setAlias ( '@frontend' , dirname ( dirname ( __DIR__ ) ) . '/frontend' );
Yii::setAlias ( '@backend' , dirname ( dirname ( __DIR__ ) ) . '/backend' );
```

The path you are providing is also wrong because Yii is inside the **`backend/web/`** not at the root of `backend` app from where you are trying to upload.

What i would suggest is to define your path inside the **`common/config/bootstrap.php`** like below

```
Yii::setAlias('@uploadDir',realpath(Yii::getAlias('@frontend').'/web/img/temp/'));
```

and then change your code to the following

```
public function actionImageUpload()
{
    $model = new MyNews();

    $imageFile = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'img');
    $directory = Yii::getAlias('@uploadDir');

    if ($imageFile != null) { //can't saveAs() file into my ../img/temp/ folder
        $uid = 'qqqq';
        $fileName = $uid . '.' . $imageFile->extension;
        $filePath = $directory . $fileName;
        if ($imageFile->saveAs($filePath)) {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success','The file has been uploaded successfuly');
            return $this->redirect('index');
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you!! if I add 3-4 file and how save path in db and when update how read from db?

Comment: you can loop through the files to save them in case of multiple , you should add another question for update part as this one is related to wrong paths for uploading @BehruzBahronov